# GWT 2.4 - Deploying on Web server

Tags: java, mysql, gwt

A client send me a project developing in GWT 2.4. It using three MYSQL tables. I am running the project in dev mode and work fine.

But when I am doing `Project->Right Click->Google->GWT Compile` and I am uploading the war directory to my web server I can't connect to Mysql.

This is my first time using this technology. Am I doing something wrong? I must upload something else? except war director

Answer (score 0):

along with GWT Compile, make sure you have all your .class files as well under WEB-INF/classes directory. You can create your .war file either by using any build script (Maven/Ant etc) or by exporting war using eclipse.

sample Maven script for you to create war file.

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>[SOURCE_PACKAGE_PATH]</groupId>
<artifactId>[APP_NAME]</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>[APP_NAME]</name>

<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    <gwtVersion>2.4.0</gwtVersion>
    <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    ... ADD Another dependencies related to your project
</dependencies>
<build>
    <!-- Final Name for the war. Should be commented if you will be tracking 
        War file snapshots. Will change as per version mentioned above -->
    <finalName>[WAR_NAME]</finalName>

    <!-- Generate compiled stuff in the folder used for developing mode -->
    <outputDirectory>war/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.gwt.xml</include>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>

        <!-- Delete gwt generated stuff -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>target</directory>
                    </fileset>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>.gwt-tmp</directory>
                    </fileset>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>war/[APP_NAME]</directory>
                    </fileset>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>war/WEB-INF/classes</directory>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>src</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
                    <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
                    <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
                    <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <!-- JS is only needed in the package phase, this speeds up testing -->
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>gwtcompile</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <!-- <configuration> </configuration> -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <!-- Plugin configuration. There are many available options, see gwt-maven-plugin 
                documentation at codehaus.org -->
            <configuration>
                <logLevel>INFO</logLevel>
                <style>OBFUSCATED</style>
                <!-- URL that should be automatically opened in the GWT shell (gwt:run). -->
                <runTarget>[TARGET PAGE]</runTarget>
                <module>${project.groupId}.[APP_NAME]</module>
                <!-- Location of the develop-mode web application structure (gwt:run). -->
                <hostedWebapp>target/www</hostedWebapp>
                <!-- Ask GWT to create the Story of Your Compile (SOYC) (gwt:compile) -->
                <compileReport>true</compileReport>
                <copyWebapp>true</copyWebapp>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Copy static web files before executing GWT:RUN -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/www</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>war</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>war</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                <webXml>war/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                <webappDirectory>${webappDirectory}</webappDirectory>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>war</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.*</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: I want to run it in Apache server. Into a web hosting server page. How can I create this .war file from eclipse?

Comment: Are you using Server side Java or it is based on PHP or python.

Comment: i am using server side java. Updated my answer with sample maven script.

Answer (score 0):

Your war(or otherwise web server) needs to provide libraries and classes necessary to run war on web server(Tomcat e.g.). Try to use Ant script e.g. warbuilder.xml , which should look something like this:

```
<project name="sourceCodeDirName" basedir="." default="default">

<target name="default" depends="buildwar"></target>

<target name="buildwar">
    <war basedir="war" destfile="gwt.war" webxml="war/WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <exclude name="WEB-INF/**" />
        <webinf dir="war/WEB-INF/">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
            <include name="classes/**" />
        </webinf>
    </war>
</target>

</project>
```

NOTE 1: basedir="." means you placed warbuilder.xml in root of your project. 
NOTE 2 :For me this worked correctly, only difference I copied classes folder manually after war was unpacked. I realized that it could be done with  so I added only that raw in script.
NOTE 3 : This Ant script should be called after GWT compile.

Comment: I am puting this warbuilder.xml at my project root dir (where build.xml is) and after GWT Compile I am (right click it) and run as Ant Build (from Eclipse)? After that which folders am I upload at my web server? war folder and www?

Comment: you should deploy only war file.

Comment: And how I am runnning  a war file from web server? (Apache?) Buildfile: C:\Users\batsakidis\workspace\AegeanExplorer\warbuilder.xml
buildwar:
      [war] Building war: C:\Users\batsakidis\workspace\AegeanExplorer\gwt.war
default:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 13 seconds

Comment: If you are using e.g Tomcat copy gwt.war to /%Tomcat_Dir%/webapss. Star(restart) Tomcat and you should be able to access your app to localhost:8080/gwt